# How to save and reuse Cookies in C#?

Tags: c#, http, cookies, cookiecontainer

i`m trying to use cookies in my c# application which is consuming a web service. Login method is working but when i try to use change password method it gives 401 status code.

**HTTP.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;

namespace RemoteSynchronizer
{
    class HTTP
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = null;
        public static CookieContainer contain;


        public HTTP()
        {
            contain = new CookieContainer();
        }

        public int postData(string url, StringBuilder data)
        {

            int status;
            Uri address = new Uri(url);

            request = WebRequest.Create(address) as HttpWebRequest;
            request.CookieContainer = contain;

            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            request.KeepAlive = true;

            byte[] byteData = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data.ToString());

            request.ContentLength = byteData.Length;

            using (Stream postStream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                postStream.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length);
            }

            using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
            {
                status = (int)response.StatusCode;
            }


            return status;
        }


/// <summary>
/// /////////////////////////
/// </summary>
/// <param name="url"></param>
/// <param name="data"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
/// 

        public int change(string url, StringBuilder data)
        {
            int status;
            Uri address = new Uri(url);

            request = WebRequest.Create(address) as HttpWebRequest;

            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            request.CookieContainer = contain;

            byte[] byteData = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data.ToString());

            request.ContentLength = byteData.Length;

            using (Stream postStream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                postStream.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length);
            }

            using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
            {
                status = (int)response.StatusCode;
            }

            return status;
        }
    }
}
```

How can i save cookie to reuse in other class?

Comment: Have you initialized your contain CookiaContainer? If not, you are just saying to not use it.

Comment: I`ve edited my code but still the same error. I want to use CookieContainer because in next class i`ll call the change method fromm HTTP class. but there is need of save the login cookie.